# Работа с элементами localstorage

Tags: javascript, jquery

Я имею множество элементов в `localstorage` (которые динамически генерируются). Я хочу по клику на определенный див сделать их неактивными (удалить), но по клику на другой элемент сделать возможность вернуть их всех обратно.

Дело в том, что у одного посетителя моего проекта может быть несколько профилей. Для одного профиля должны хранится одни значения в `localstorage`, для другого - другие.

Мне нужно сделать возможность переходить из одного профиля в другой, и что бы элементы в `localstorage` тоже менялись.

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Если на столько все просто, то может те элементы просто делать `display: hidden`?  А если хотите использовать именно `localstorage`, как написано в заголовке темы, то в чем проблема? он клик - заносите в хранилище, онклик другой элемент - достаете.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский всё, к сожалению, не так просто, и просто display:hidden в моем случае не подойдет. Дело в том, что у одного посетителя моего проекта может быть несколько профилей. Для одного профиля должны хранится одни значения в localstorage, для другого - другие. Мне нужно сделать возможность переходить из одного профиля в другой, и что бы элементы в localstorage тоже менялись

Comment: Добавьте это в описание, чтоб люди более полно представляли, что нужно вам.

Comment: подмешивайте в ключи localstorage id юзера, делов то.

Answer (score 1):

Как указывалось в комментариях нужно сохранять в `localStorage` "профиль с идентификатором пользователя как ключ" или идентификатором (типом) профиля. А можно вообще хранить все профили в `JSON` объекте и обрабатывать логикой приложения, нужное забирать, лишнее отсекать. Сам профиль может быть и локальной переменной и свойством нужного объекта или глобальным свойством `window`.

[смотрите очень простой пример переключения и загрузки из localStorage](https://jsfiddle.net/z8xnozfr/14/)

Это очень простоя реализация, только для демонстрации логики загрузки и передачи объекта в приложение.